# Imaginary quadratic fields with prime class number

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, algebraic-number-theory, number-fields

Let $K$ be an imaginary quadratic field, with class number equal to an odd prime, say $h_K = p$.

In the proof Proposition 2.4 of [this paper](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/experimental-mathematics/volume-11/issue-4/Noncyclotomic-Z_p-Extensions-of-Imaginary-Quadratic-Fields/em/1057864657.pdf), Fukuda and Komatsu write,

*"Since $h_K = p$, there exists a prime number $q$ with $q \equiv 3$ mod $4$ such that $K = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{−q})$".*

This is a result I have never heard of before.  Fukuda and Komatsu don't give a reference for this, and my search on google didn't turn up anything.  Does anyone know a reference for this?

Comment: You want probably $p$ odd: $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-10})$ has class number $2$.

Comment: It is a classic result that the class number of a quadratic number field is even if the discriminant divides by 2 primes (proven for example in the classic book of Borevich and Shafarevich); since $-q$ is a discriminant only when $q=4k+3$ the claim (with odd prime class number) follows

Comment: @abx Thank you, I've fixed this in my question.